# The "execute" command does not work in my discord bot

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js, bots

I am writing a discord bot replacement for groovy since it got banned but every time I try to do the -play command the bot shows an error (photo of error is linked) I don't know what I did wrong can someone pls help?! (code is also linked) I changed the bot code. I tride a lot of things i found on the internet but nothig sems to work plys help me. its a musick bot btw. thank you:)

The error is tah it can not read "execute" as a command.

Main code-

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Groovy is back!');
});


client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message. author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    } else if (command == 'youtube'){
        message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwCs6NRBb9XaEKa787TyrQg')
    } else if (command == 'groovy'){
        message.channel.send('https://groovy.bot')
    } else if (command === 'leave') {
        client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'play') {
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
    }
});



client.login('ODg3NDU1NjY5NjkzODU3Nzky.EUFZwf.ZK8TaB2tIVdww8hzPFQe6NBbRzk');
```

-play code:

```
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

-leave code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'leave',
description: 'stop the bot and leave the channel',
async execute(message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("You need to be in a voice channel to stop the music!");
    await voiceChannel.leave();
    await message.channel.send('Leaving channel :smiling_face_with_tear:')

}
}
```

Comment: Remove your bot token of your question as soon as possible!

Comment: @Zero just removing wont do the trick. Please regenerate your token. It can still be found in the past edits page!

Comment: "does not work" is not enough information. What debugging have you done? I assume the *actual* error is `execute is not a function`. Please include the error to help us